# implicit declaration of function 'link'; did you mean 'unlink'?,implicit declaration of function 'symlink'

Tags: c, windows, unix, mingw-w64, mingw32

Below is my code for Creation of Hardlink and Softlink...

Code(Filename:b.c):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
  if(argc==3)
  {
  printf("Hard linking %s and %s",argv[1],argv[2]);
  if(link(argv[1],argv[2])==0)
  printf("\nHard link created");
  else
  printf("\nLink not created");
  }
  else if(argc==4)
  {
  printf("Soft linking %s and %s",argv[1],argv[2]);
  if(symlink(argv[1],argv[2])==0)
  printf("\nSoft link created");
  else
  printf("\nLink not created");
  }
}
```

> **The same code works just fine in Ubuntu(Linux)**

I get this error(I am using MiNGW C compiler in Windows 10):

```
b.c: In function 'main':
b.c:12:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'link'; did you mean 'unlink'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
12 |   if(link(argv[1],argv[2])==0)
|      ^~~~
|      unlink
b.c:20:6: warning: implicit declaration of function 'symlink' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
20 |   if(symlink(argv[1],argv[2])==0)
|      ^~~~~~~       
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
C:\Users\vbpat\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2r6Yv5.o:b.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `link'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
C:\Users\vbpat\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2r6Yv5.o:b.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `symlink'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The functions you are using are likely linux specific and do not exist on windows

Comment: WinAPI has [`CreateHardLinkW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createhardlinkw) and [`CreateSymbolicLinkW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsymboliclinkw).

Comment: OT: what happens when `argc` is neither 3 nor 4?  Suggest output a `usage` statement to `stderr`, similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s (list of parameters)\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: the error messages look like the support files for mingw have not been installed

Answer (score 1):

These functions are defined by POSIX and provided by C implementations that attempt to conform to or that are loosely modeled on POSIX or descended from the lineage POSIX standardized. The MSVC runtime, which mingw uses, is not such an implementation.

If you want to be able to build programs using the standard POSIX interfaces on Windows, you need [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or (in the [near?] future) [midipix](https://midipix.org/). Or build Linux programs rather than native Windows programs using WSL - this is probably the easiest option when your goal isn't actually to make Windows applications.